# Prove that $AX = B$ Is Consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is $n \times m$ and $B$ is $n \times p$.  We are given that:
$$c^tA = 0 \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ c^tB = 0$$
The text says that this relation implies that $AX = B$ is consistent since each column of $B$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.  How is that so?  To me, $c^tA$ looks more like a linear combination of the rows of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

By [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofLinearAlgebra.html),

$$N(A^T)=R(A)^\perp$$

that is the nullspace of $A^T$ is equal to the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of $R(A)$, the range of $A$.

The information given in the question tells us that

$$N(A^T)=N(B^T)$$

Hence

$$R(A)^\perp=R(B)^\perp$$

Since $R(A)$ and $R(B)$ are finite dimensional,

$$R(A)=R(B).$$

Hence $AX=B$ is consistent.